# How can i measure Gain in multisim 14

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, multisim

I have an Operational Amplifier in Multisim 14 but i don't know how can i measure the Gain of this circuit. Is there any automatic way to do this?

[image: Operational Amplifier example in Multisim 14]

Comment: 1) *measuring* is done on a bench, this is a simulator, you're **simulating**. 2) the + input of the opamp is floating, you must connect it somewhere. 3) what is gain ? It is the ratio between output amplitude and input amplitude. Determine those, divide and you have your gain.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure gain with the following steps;

1- Click Simulate > Instruments > Measurement Probe

2- Place the probe on the wire between the voltage source and the resistor.

3- Click Simulate > Instruments > Preset Measurement Probes > Voltage with reference to probe

4- Select Probe1 as the reference

5- Place the probe on the output. Notice that the visible measurements includes gain.

Comment: Thanks a lot wooz! I followed your instructions but i need one more tip. In the link of the image below i have Vgain(dc) = -188k. Should i divide Vgain(dc) with V(dc) of probe 1 to find the actual gain?

https://ibb.co/crEwfk

Comment: I am sorry to be late. You can remove Vgain(dc) or V(dc) value from probe2. 
1- Right click probe2 and select properties.
2- In parameters section you can turn off the parameters you don't want to appear.